# forwarding in c++ functions with auto type parameters

Tags: c++, c++17

With forwarding functions using a template parameter, the idiom is to forward using the `typename T`, e.g.

```cpp
template <typename T>
void fwd(T &&x) { 
  some_func(std::forward<T>(x));
}
```

Equivalent approach when using a forwarding function (or lambda) that takes an auto type parameter:

```cpp
void fwd(auto &&x) { 
   some_func(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x));
}
```

In the above `decltype(x)` is not necessarily the same as the type of `T` in the previous example. E.g. `fwd(3)` deduces `T` to `int` while `decltype(x)` is `int&&`.

Can someone explain why we use `T` in one case vs. `decltype(x)` as the template parameter to `std::forward` above? Is the end result always guaranteed to be identical based on the implementation of `std::forward`?

Comment: [`std::forward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) applies `std::remove_reference` to its type parameter first thing

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, in addition to the type parameter presumably the return type also matters, i.e. types T&& and U&& are identical where ```U = std::remove_reference_t<T>``` ?

Comment: `T&&` produces `int&&` whether `T` is `int` or `int&&`. It follows the same reference collapsing rules as the original type deduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void fwd(auto &&x)` is a c++20 shorthand for  `template <typename T> void fwd(T &&x)`. But in this case you don't have  type to refer to. You can write this:

```
void fwd(auto &&x) { 
   using T = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(x)>;
   some_func(std::forward<T>(x));
}
```

Here T equals to T in original version, but it doesn't matter much.
`std::forward<T>`  and `std::forward<std::remove_reference_t<T>>` are equal, because its signature defined like this:

```
template< class T >
constexpr T&& forward( std::remove_reference_t<T>&& t ) noexcept;
```